# Implementation of CRUD with Grails framework

Tags: grails, crud

I've been searching all day for an answer to my problem, and don't seem to be able to find an answer.

I'm trying to implement a CRUD web application using Grails, with the IntelliIDEA IDE. Whereas with JSF i could use primefaces which allowed me to do this with general ease, i am disappointed to see, or at least seems to be that way, that the framework is a step backwards when it comes to development of html pages.

All i want is to have a table that is populated from data that is coming from a controller, and whenever i add a record it is also displayed in this table. I want to be able to edit any record on this table and also remove records. It would be awesome if there could be a component like primefaces datatables that allows me to do this easily, without having to use JavaScript. I've taken a look to the Dojo plugin, but it's so outdated and incomprehensible to me that i have discarded this option, mainly because there is no documentation on the site on how to use it with Grails, specifically.

Also, i do not want to use scaffolding. I am trying to learn how to do this from scratch, and it is of my understanding that it doesn't work too well with domains with many to many relationship, for example.

In a nutshell, what I am looking for is the best way to make a CRUD application on Grails that doesn't involve the use of scaffolding.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go through "**Grails in Action**" book and follow the creation of web application "Quote of the Day" and "Hubbub", don't use scaffolding instead create your own views and controller using documentation provided.

This will help you to understand basic CRUD operations in Grails.

And also looking into documentation http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html

See if this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are aware that the scaffolding also can generate code for you to learn from and continue your work from there (i.e. it doesn't have to happen magically behind the curtains). I would say that is the typical means of starting out with Grails and CRUD.

Otherwise, no Dojo probably won't help you out a lot. Maybe have a look at some other plugin, for instance the [Easygrid plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/easygrid)? It is based on Javascript though, which most solutions do.

The "Grails in Action" recommendation is probably your best bet for the long-term, learning it from the pro's rather than learning-by-doing/top-to-bottom CRUD-style.